# Javascript decorator listener

Tags: javascript, decorator

I'm messing around with decorators for a bit, having an Angular background i'm trying to wrap my head around the `HostListener` decorator.

This is how far i got:

```
class Demo {
        counter = 0;

        @Listen("mousemove") onMouseMove(e?) {
            console.log(this);

            this.counter++;
        }
    }

    export function Listen(name) {
        return (target, key, descriptor) => {

            window.addEventListener(name, oldValue.bind(target));


            return descriptor;
        };
    }

    new Demo();
```

This is more or less the implementation only problem is passing the target/this reference as target is not initialised.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, i'm using Vue so this might not be everyones answer, basically what i'm doing is calling the function just once in Vue you can add a mixin and inside this mixin the `beforeMount` hook will be called, thus allowing me here to call it once.

Decorator updated code:

```
export function Listen(name) {
    return function (target, key, descriptor) {
        if (!target.subscriptions) target.subscriptions = [];


        add(target, "Listen", key);

        if (process.client) {
            const oldValue = descriptor.value;

            descriptor.value = function() {
                target.subscriptions.push(
                    target.$eventManager.add(window, name, oldValue.bind(this))
                );
            };

            return descriptor;
        }

        return descriptor;
    };
}

const add = (target, name, functionName) => {
    if(!target.decorators) target.decorators = {};
    if(!target.decorators[name]) target.decorators[name] = [];

    target.decorators[name].push(functionName);
};
```

Vue mixin:

```
Vue.mixin({
    beforeMount: function() {
        if(this.decorators && this.decorators.Listen) {
            this.decorators.Listen.forEach(key => this[key]());
        }
    },
    destroyed: function () {
        this.$subscriptionManager.remove(this.subscriptions);
    }
});
```